# What are usage hours in cloud services

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, cloud, paas, iaas

I have seen various cloud computing services offering a free number of hours per month. What exactly they mean? Are they just clock hours or they have some special meaning?

Comment: Not a coding question and varies per provider

Answer (score 2):

Cloud computing is billed hourly for each instance (server that you are using).

If your provider offers 48 free hours, you can use this by running a single instance for 48 hours, or two instances for 24 hours (and so on).

Comment: What if I run an instance for a single minute? Will it count as 1 hour?

Comment: @VarunAgw This depend on your provider. On Amazon Web Services, billing is indeed hourly. On Google Compute Engine, you pay by-the-minute after the first 15 minutes.